# Javascript: Simple Function - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, function, undefined

I have a function that simply returns the longest property of a given array.

It's a for loop that assigns the looped property to a variable, with the length of the property is longer than that of the variable.

And at last it returns this new variable. But I get an error in line 10, that it can't read the length of undefined.

It seems to have a problem with **someArray[i].length** inside the for loop.

```js
function longestString(i) {

      // i will be an array.
      // return the longest string in the array
      var someArray = i;
      console.log(someArray);
      var longestItem = someArray[0];
      console.log(longestItem);
      
      for (i = 0; someArray.length; i++) {
        if (longestItem.length < someArray[i].length) {
          console.log(longestItem);
          console.log(someArray[i]);
          longestItem = someArray[i];
        }
      }

      document.write(longestItem);
      console.log(longestItem);
      return longestItem;
    }

    longestString(['a', 'ab', 'abc']) // should return 'abc'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you use the same name for the function parameter and your loop counter???

Comment: `i<someArray.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for-loop`'s condition has error.

It should be like given below.

```
for (i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++)
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/0no1019L/).

Here is the complete code.

```js
function longestString(i) {

  // i will be an array.
  // return the longest string in the array
  var someArray = i;
  document.write(someArray); // just testing
  var longestItem = someArray[0];

  for (i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) { //Changes in the condition
    if (longestItem.length < someArray[i].length) {
      longestItem = someArray[i];
    }
  }

  document.write(longestItem);
  return longestItem;
}

longestString(['a', 'ab', 'abc']) // should return 'abc'
```

Comment: Thanks Shrinivas, after the timer is up, I will accept your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @LoveAndHappiness Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't use the same name `i`for the function parameter and then in the for loop counter, you may put yourself in really big troubles.

Second thing, your loop doesn't have a stop condition you missed `i<someArray.length`, it should be like this:

```
for (i = 0; i<someArray.length; i++) {
    if (longestItem.length < someArray[i].length) {
      console.log(longestItem);
      console.log(someArray[i]);
      longestItem = someArray[i];
    }
  }
```

Last thing use `console.log()` or `console.dir()` to **debug/test** instead of `document.write()` because **it's a very very bad practice**.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors on your for loop:

You are using an `i` function parameter which you are using again in your for loop. Try to use a different variable name inside your for loop or at least define the variable with `var` (to retain the scope), otherwise you will shadow the variable declared as function parameter.

The second one is that you forget to include the test condition into the loop.

```js
function longestString(len) {

  // i will be an array.
  // return the longest string in the array
  var someArray = len;
  var longestItem = someArray[0];
  var length = someArray.length;
  
  for (var i = 0 ; i < length; i++) {
    if (longestItem.length < someArray[i].length) {
      longestItem = someArray[i];
    }
  }

  console.log(longestItem);
  return longestItem;
}

longestString(['a', 'ab', 'abc']) // should return 'abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's more than one longest string. I'd suggest looking at the [Array instance iteration methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods).

```js
var array = ['a', 'abc', 'ab', 'def'];
var maxlen = Math.max.apply(null, array.map(function(string){
    return string.length;
}));
var longest = array.filter(function(string){
    return string.length === maxlen;
});

var pre = document.createElement('pre');
pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(longest);
document.body.appendChild(pre);
```